# What is the point of Jason asking Kaneki to count backwards by 1000-7?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

What is the point of asking Kaneki the question 1000-7 at several points during his torture?

Is there some character development behind the reason hid did that? Or is it a known method of torture?

Answer (score 4):

2 reasons:

1. First one being so that Kaneki doesn't go insane
2. To keep him mentally aware so that he constantly feels pain instead of trying to ignore it. By keeping him mentally engaged it prevents Kaneki from ignoring the constant pain cycle (although he later goes on to say that it helped him keep his mind on something else besides the pain - linking back to bullet 1, keeping him sane)

Source: [Chapter 61 page 9](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-B8nCS_B4eNw/WAL-kSds4gI/AAAAAADkbLI/Xy6Akhf23hY/w1900/MR-23454-452618-9.jpg) :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a method of real life torture said to be used in combination with strong drugs.

### Note, some of these things might be considered brutal, graphic to some viewers. So discretion is advised

See for example the [Edgewood arsenal human experimentations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgewood_Arsenal_human_experiments)
or [this podcast](https://soundcloud.com/lastpodcastontheleft/episode140-edgewood-part-2-disco-soup)

They go quite in-depth on how this is useful in torture, and what the side effects are.

Comment: Also to add in to that it is a very common torture tactic to keep the victim's mind focused on something specific that in quantifiable. This way they don't lose their mind, they can't relax, and they stay concious because they believe they will be hurt less if they comply. This is why whenever he walked into the room he asked `what's the count at now?`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to locate the source, but Kaneki said it was to make sure he didn't go insane, and Jason developed that from his torturer.